# Unable to retrieve web Apps from subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, server-explorer

Hi in my xamarin project am getting this issues when I try to open the azure web apps from visual studio 2015. [image]

why this is coming I tried to add the subscription from the visual studio but doesn't work any can guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed this is the IDE issue. Based on my understanding, you could try to install [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2015) -3.0](https://aka.ms/azuresdk2015_300) which is released at 3/7/2017, then find out whether this upgrade could help you to solve this issue. Here is the release download, you could refer to [it](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/).